# Redirect in 5 seconds when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

What I want to do is when the submit button is pressed, the user gets redirected after 5 seconds when submitted the form.

code:

```
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

I tried this and other variants but these redirect instantly.

Comment: If you want to use pure PHP, you can use the [`sleep()` function](http://ca2.php.net/sleep)

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit the form? Can you show more of the `form` (eg: the `method` and `action` of the `form`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is

```
 setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();}, 5000)
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work if the form gets posted to the server without JS.

Comment: @putvande, he is already using "onclick", hence Javascript in the client side... I believe there is no significant difference apart from the delay.

Answer (score 0):

From `onClick` call a javascript function, and from the function wait and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a form and then redirect, then you need to use ajax calls to the php page to store the data and then redirect yourself after a 5 second sleep.

Else, if you want the form to be submitted only after 5 seconds, then simple add a sleep timer at let javascript submit the form afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this on you button call event :

```
setTimeout("document.forms['form_name'].submit()",5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using jQuery:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $("#myForm").submit();
        },
        5000
    );
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/TeCuq/